# Modification of a logarithmic function with an infinite product equation

Tags: logarithms, roots, infinite-product

I have the following logarithmic equation:
$$y(x)=\ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }(x-a_{n})\right)$$
To find the roots of $y(x)$, we put $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }(x-a_{n})=1$$ because, as you know,  $\ln(f(x))=0$ if $f(x)=1$. Unfortunately, this will complicate things. Is there any mathematical trick to include a one inside the log equation so that we obtain $$\ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }(x-a_{n})+1\right)=0$$ through which we achieve $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }(x-a_{n})+1=1$$ leading to eliminate  the two ones and thus to obtain $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }(x-a_{n})=0$$.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other way other than finding the roots of the polynomial $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }(x-a_{n})-1$.

Comment: @P.S.Dester The product is infinite, so that's not a polynomial.

Comment: @jjagmath omg, that is true. For some reason, I thought it was finite. That makes things worse.

Comment: If $x$ is a root of $$y(x)=\ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }(x-a_{n})\right),$$ 

then 

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }(x-a_{n})=1,$$

which means that 

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\prod_{n=1}^{k }(x-a_{n}) \right)=1$$

If $x-a_n \not\to 1,\ $ then this is not possible. Therefore, if $x$ is a root of $$y(x)=\ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }(x-a_{n})\right),$$ 

then we certainly have that $x = \left(\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\right) +1.$

Comment: So, $y(x)=0$ has a root $x = \left(\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\right) +1,$ which is true only if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ converges.

Comment: Where this function comes from? Can you give an example of a sequence $a_n$ such that the infinite product converge to a non-trivial function?

Comment: Perhaps, @SalahOdeh meant $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }(1-\frac{x}{a_n})$, because $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }(x-a_{n})$ does not converge in any neighborhood around $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n+1$.